# How to disable summernote on clicking outside summernote editor?

Tags: jquery, html, summernote

is there any way to disable **summernote** by clicking outside the **summernote**.

Here is my summer note, now the issue is when i click any where outside the editor including the tool bar it is getting disabled which I don't want to.

[image]

***Code for disable summer note.***

```
$('#textarea').on('summernote.blur', function(event) {
    $('#textarea').summernote('destroy');
    $('#textarea').hide();
});
```

Comment: So you want to disable it on blur or keep focus even on blur? At first you ask how *disable summernote* and at the end you say you don't want to disable summernote

Comment: I want to disable summer note by clicking outside the summernote, but it should not be disable by click on toolbar

Comment: Check `event` target. If it's toolbar, do nothing.

Comment: @Justinas, i do that but, i'm getting textarea in event.
$('#textarea').on('summernote.blur', function(event) {

    var target = event.target.nodeName;
    console.log(target);
});

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working for me -

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-9 dv100 txtarea pd-8" id="summernote"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).hasClass('txtarea') ) {
       $('.txtarea').summernote('destroy');               
    }
});
```